# Select and browse functionality for component GUI extension

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

We have developed a GUI extension which invokes custom MVC based application hosted on CM servers.

> As part of that custom application, we want to enable select and
>   browse functionality for the components based on particular schema.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: your question is not very clear. Could you please give details on what you exactly want to mean with "select and browse" ? Can you also specify what you have already tried or which problems you encounter.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you  want to open a item selector popup, with a browser filtered by schema.
In order to do this you need to use a filter.

In your extension js code:

```
 // Open item selector popup
        var filter = {
            conditions:
            {
                ItemTypes: [$const.ItemType.COMPONENT],
                BasedOnSchema: [yourSchema],
                Publication: rootId,
                InPublication: rootId,
                ShowNewItems: false
            }
        };


        p.ItemPopup = $popup.create($cme.Popups.ITEM_SELECT.URL.format(rootId), $cme.Popups.ITEM_SELECT.FEATURES, { filter: filter });
```

Comment: This is what we are looking for however not from GUI extension. GUI extension is loading a MVC application, we want to enable this functionality from that MVC application. Can you suggest?

Comment: Then  maybe you can use CoreService to load the list of items in a custom view of your MVC aplication.  You can find something useful about in this extension: http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx      Hope it helps.

Comment: That was the last option however we wanted to try if we can use something inbuilt instead of developing our own implementation.